Odd use of { } in legacy C program and incompatible pointer conversion
I have some legacy C code that contains the following line:
char line[max_line] = {NULL}

where in stddef.h, NULL is defined as:
#define NULL ((void*)0)

When trying to compile the code with icx, I am getting a error about incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'char' with an expression of type 'void *'
Two questions:

I've only seen curly braces used in C to delineate a block of code.  What is the meaning of {NULL}?
How should I modify the code to eliminate the incompatible pointer conversion error?

I tried:
char line[max_chars] = "";

and that compiled OK, but I'm still confused by the meaning of {NULL}

Curly braces are also used in array initialisation. This line is initialising the array of char types to NULL. Please update to show the compiler command and error output.

Aside: char line[max_chars] = ""; is initialising all array elements to 0.  The answers on this question may help to clarify things a bit.

... as char line[max_chars] = {0}; or char line[max_chars] = {'\0'}; also would do, which seems to be the intent of the original code.

BTW char x[10] = ""; is the same as char x[10] = {0}; /* or '\0' */. Since C23 you can also do char x[10] = {}; /* invalid pre C23 */ with the same meaning.

(char line[max_line] = {whatever_val}; initializes the first element, not all the elements, to the provided value. It zeros out the other elements. You can't fill an array with fives with int arr[ARR_SIZE] = {5};.)

It would seem that the person who wrote the original code was confused. So getting it to compile might be the least of your problems - there's reason to believe it might be full of bugs.

Maybe, the compiler that was initially used to build that code, provided something like #define NULL 0 or just ignored the implicit conversion.

A long time ago, before POSIX defined that NULL should be the equivalent of ((void *)0), it was common to define #define NULL 0L or something similar.  Old code used that as a verbose synonym for 0.  The code you are working with probably dates back to that era, or the coder who wrote it does.

Conjecture: This code was written by somebody who confused the NULL macro with the null character. The NULL macro is intended for use as a null pointer constant and should not be used to represent a character or integer value.
The code could have worked without complaint in some C implementations because the C standard permits NULL to be defined as 0 (or other integer constant expression with the value zero). So the code would be char line[max_line] = {0}, which initializes the array to a zero first element (explicitly) and zero in the remaining elements (by default). (There should also be a semicolon at the end, or other continuation of the declaration.)
In your C implementation, NULL is defined as ((void*)0), which is also allowed by the C standard. This form is generally preferable, as making NULL a pointer type allows the compiler to detect some errors, as has occurred here. (Allowing the other form, an integer constant, was likely a deference to existing C implementations.)


I've only seen curly braces used in C to delineate a block of code. What is the meaning of {NULL}?


This is normal syntax for listing the initial values for an array or structure, as in int array[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };. (Braces may also be used, optionally, for initializing a scalar, as in int x = { 4 };.)


How should I modify the code to eliminate the incompatible pointer conversion error?


Change NULL to 0 or, to emphasize it is a character, '\0': char line[max_line] = { '\0' };. Using "" as you did is also okay.

You can use NULL to initialize a pointer (using the * sign) (nullptr since C23). However, in this specific case, you are trying to initialize a char with NULL, which cannot work because it is not a pointer.

If you want to use dynamic allocation:

unsigned int max_line = 12;

char *line = malloc(sizeof(char) * max_line);


If you want to use static allocation:

unsigned int max_line = 12;

char line[max_line];

memset(line, '\0', max_line);

